# Is there a way to store struct variables in an array in C?

Tags: c, struct

Is there way to make an array of structs with just its variables? For example, instead of using this:

```
struct Employee
{
  int age;
  char name[50];
  int salary;
};
struct Employee  Employees[4];
    Employees[4] = {
           {25, "Suresh", 25000},
           {24, "Tutorial", 28000},
           {22, "Gateway", 35000},
           {27, "Mike", 20000}
};//example I found
```

I would like to use my struct variables that I have already filled in an array of structs.

I went off the example from above and encounter an error `expected expression before '{' token`

Using the code below:

```
struct patients p1;
struct patients p2;
struct patients p3;
struct patients p4;
struct patients patientsArray[4];

/*patient 1 specification */
p1.id=1;
p1.severity=2;
p1.firstName="Joe";
p1.lastName="Curcio";
p1.state="Patient has arrived";
p1.time_spent = 0;
/*patient 2 specification */
p2.id=2;
p2.severity=3;
p2.firstName="Sam";
p2.lastName="Washington";
p2.state="Patient has arrived";
p2.time_spent = 0;
/*patient 3 specification */
p3.id=3;
p3.severity=5;
p3.firstName="Mary";
p3.lastName="Smith";
p3.state="Patient has arrived";
p3.time_spent = 0;
/*patient 4 specification */
p4.id=4;
p4.severity=3;
p4.firstName="Joal";
p4.lastName="Blackwell";
p4.state="Patient has arrived";
p4.time_spent = 0;
patientsArray[4]={p1,p2,p3,p4};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use:

```
struct patients* patientsArray[4] = {&p1, &p2, &p3, &p4};
```

This will allow you to initialize the array before filling in the structures (like your code shows) and end up with the result you want.  The only difference is that you will have to access items from the array using `->` instead of `.`.

Another option is to use:

```
struct patients patientsArray[4];
struct patients* p1 = &patientsArray[0];
struct patients* p2 = &patientsArray[1];
struct patients* p3 = &patientsArray[2];
struct patients* p4 = &patientsArray[3];
```

The idea is generally the same, except your array contains structures and your individual objects are pointers.

If you have to keep everything as `struct` and can't use pointers, then you'll probably want to do something like this:

```
struct patients p1;
struct patients p2;
struct patients p3;
struct patients p4;
struct patients patientsArray[4];

// Initialize individual objects
p1.id = 1;
...

// Initialize array
patientsArray[0] = p1;
patientsArray[1] = p2;
patientsArray[2] = p3;
patientsArray[3] = p4;
```

When everything's a `struct`, you have to fill in the individual structures before copying them to the array.

What you definitely *can't* do is to mass-assign values to the entire array using the brace notation that you're currently using.  That syntax is for initializers, which have to be part of the variable's declaration.  The brace doesn't make sense in a normal assignment statement, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is just remove brackets inside the array declaration.

So it will be like `patientsArray[4]={p1,p2,p3,p4};`

And the other thing is "you have to assign the value to p1,p2,p3,p4 before initializing the array"

or put this line of code way down below.

Comment: Tried that by putting the line of code all the way below p4/removing brackets inside array declaration and I am still getting variable patientsArray set but not used and expected expression before '{' token. any other suggestions you might have?

Comment: You already deleted the patientsArray[4] on the previous file right?

Comment: nope still have patientsArray[4], but yes I deleted the brackets I had in the inside surrounding p1,p2,p3,p4. Will update the code